# Delete key does not always work in IRAF's xgterm on Mac

Tags: spectroscopy

Sometimes it does not let me delete text in an xgterm terminal and outputs ^H instead.

Example:

Run IRAF:

```
xgterm -e cl
```

It opens the xgterm, there I type:

```
splot black_hole.fits[0]
Image line/aperture to plot (0:) (12): 192
```

Then I realise I made a mistake and press the Delete key on Mac, and it writes the ^H text instead:

```
Image line/aperture to plot (0:) (12): 192^H^H
```

This is very annoying. Is there a way to fix it?

Note that delete key works in xgterm initially, but breaks and writes ^H in the case above.

I've installed IRAF 2.16 through astroconda iraf-all package on Mac.

### Update

The only solution I found was to use PyRAF instead. PyRAF uses the normal Mac's terminal, which does not have those Delete key issues. I can still run the same IRAF commands in PyRAF terminal, so it works fine for me.

Comment: I had originally suggested migrating this to Unix.SE or Apple.SE however, this question is about a quirk of how IRAF (used by astronomers to analyze images and spectra) handles terminal settings.  IMO then it is on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a problem with your terminal settings.  Quoting the **Setting up IRAF** section [this page](http://mips.as.arizona.edu/~khainline/intro_to_IRAF.html), "We assume the user has defined this correctly when issuing the MKIRAF and no longer key off the unix TERM to set a default."  The page goes on to say that one should add `stty xgterm` the to your `login.cl` file (directly above the final `keep` line might be a good place).  The page linked above goes into more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I already had `stty xgterm` in my `locin.cl`.

Comment: @Evgenii Does it appear after all other mentions of `stty` and also not within a conditional block (`if (`...`) {` ... `} else {` ... `}`)?

Comment: Yes, stty xgterm is the only stty command and it is not within any other blocks.